# Error with Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql, database

Well, I work little bit with C # and I'm starting to work with Database with C # now, I've googled in several places and I am unable to identify where it is wrong, everywhere say I need to open a connection, but it is already open .

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\hour\hour\Database1.mdf");
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] (name, time) VALUES ('test',1)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure about waht you searched for. But you should search for a torutial or sample code and you would find many, like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `using`, takes care of the closing and disposal for you just in case you forget to do it explicitly.  Put it inside the try, you have the connection open command outside the try so it wont catch any connection error. You probably want to look at parameterizing your command too.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\hour\hour\Database1.mdf"))
{
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (name, time) VALUES (@name,@time)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "test");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", 1);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, complex seemed to me (in my understanding of C #), and helped me understand better how I can work in .NET language, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\hour\hour\Database1.mdf");
        try
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] (name, time) VALUES ('test',1)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: @GtOkAi you made two mistakes 
1) you open connection before required
2) the main mistake you made is not passing connection string to command object
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign the command to the connection. eg:

```
    private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
    {
        string queryString = 
            "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                   connectionString))
        {

//----

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                queryString, connection);


//----
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                        reader[0], reader[1]));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Always call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```